# AJAX/XMLHttpRequest and Cookies

Tags: ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

How do the various popular user agents respond to Set-Cookie headers returned as to response to an XMLHttpRequest? Does the Javascript need to affirm or instruct the user agent to acknowledge that header?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to [this questiion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289002/can-headers-be-sent-in-an-ajax-request) seems to indicate that it works fine. I'm 90% sure that I've done it in the past and had no problems too.